# javascript & radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to activate/disable a textinput by activating/disabling a radio button.

html:

```
<input name="test" type="radio" value="one" onclick="activate();"/>

<input class="" name="info" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" disabled>

<input name="test" type="radio" value="two""/>
```

javascript:

```
    function activate(){
        document.forms[0].info.disabled = !document.forms[0].test[0].checked;
    }
```

when u activate the 1st radio button, the input text should be activated. when u activate 2nd button, it should be disabled.

but this code doesnt work. does anyone know better?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `activate` function again when the other radio button is clicked.

Comment: wow. thx dude ! working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var rad = document.getElementsByName("test");
  for (var i=0;i<rad.length;i++) {
    rad[i].onclick=function() {
      this.form.info.disabled=this.value!="one";
  }
}
```